# Pyspark - Fetch all non null columns into a single row

Tags: pyspark

I have below requirement, need to get all the non null columns into a single row
DataFrame:

```
TRXN_CD TRXN_BR  CODE
      A    NULL  NULL
   NULL      CD  NULL
   NULL    NULL   MOR
```

Expected output as below so that it can be loaded in table.
Output Dataframe:

```
TRXN_CD TRXN_BR  CODE
      A      CD   MOR
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Are you looking for a solution or are you asking on how this would be created?

Comment: I want the output as one row/record so that i can be loaded into a Table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `first` function, ignoring null values.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

...
df = df.select(*[F.first(c, True).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
df.show(truncate=False)
```